# Fancybox not working with Simple Configurable Products (SCP)

Tags: fancybox, magento-1.8

I need some help with Javascript to get fancybox working with SCP. The following solution has not worked for me although I'm aware I'm missing some fundamental code. The first product image works perfectly opening the fancybox lightbox but once you select from the configurable dropdowns it changes the image which then does not call the lightbox and opens in the browser.

SCP advice is:
To fix, it's often just a matter of editing the `showFullImageDiv` function in the `scp_product_extension.js` file: Change `evalScripts` to true if it's not already, and possibly you'll also need to remove the code which exists in a few places which looks like: `product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint');`

I tried this but it's not just a simple matter of removing "product_zoom..." my understanding is that fancybox needs to be called replace this line of code.

Original:

```js
Product.Config.prototype.showFullImageDiv = function(productId, parentId) {
    var imgUrl = this.config.ajaxBaseUrl + "image/?id=" + productId + '&pid=' + parentId;
    var prodForm = $('product_addtocart_form');
    var destElement = false;
    var defaultZoomer = this.config.imageZoomer;

    prodForm.select('div.product-img-box').each(function(el) {
        destElement = el;
    });

    if(productId) {
        new Ajax.Updater(destElement, imgUrl, {
            method: 'get',
            evalScripts: true,
            onComplete: function() {
                //Product.Zoom needs the *image* (not just the html source from the ajax)
                //to have loaded before it works, hence image object and onload handler
                if ($('image')){
                    var imgObj = new Image();
                    imgObj.src = $('image').src;
                    imgObj.onload = function() {product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint'); };
                } else {
                    destElement.innerHTML = defaultZoomer;
                    product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint')
                }
          }
        });
    } else {
        destElement.innerHTML = defaultZoomer;
        product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint');
    }
};
```

I know I need to call fancybox in the below locations but not sure how to go about it. From what I understand fancybox is called on pageload so not sure `imgObj.onload` will even work?

```js
Product.Config.prototype.showFullImageDiv = function(productId, parentId) {
    var imgUrl = this.config.ajaxBaseUrl + "image/?id=" + productId + '&pid=' + parentId;
    var prodForm = $('product_addtocart_form');
    var destElement = false;
    var defaultZoomer = this.config.imageZoomer;

    prodForm.select('div.product-img-box').each(function(el) {
        destElement = el;
    });

    if(productId) {
        new Ajax.Updater(destElement, imgUrl, {
            method: 'get',
            evalScripts: true,
            onComplete: function() {
                //Product.Zoom needs the *image* (not just the html source from the ajax)
                //to have loaded before it works, hence image object and onload handler
                if ($('image')){
                    var imgObj = new Image();
                    imgObj.src = $('image').src;
                    imgObj.onload = CALL FANCYBOX
                } else {
                    destElement.innerHTML = defaultZoomer;
                    CALL FANCYBOX
                }
          }
        });
    } else {
        destElement.innerHTML = defaultZoomer;
        CALL FANCYBOX
    }
};
```

Unfortunately my javascript is very basic and any help on what I need to add would be gratefully received. I found a few posts with the same issue but no solution.

Thanks